# Cannot import Owlready library into Python

Tags: python, ontology, owlready

I am a beginner in Python. I am working on an ontology using [owlready](http://pythonhosted.org/Owlready/). I've installed `owlready` library on my PyCharm IDE, but there is an issue with importing `owlready` in my python code. I've tried `from owlready import *` just like in the documentation, but it always give me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/siekoo/OneDrive/Development/python/NER/onto_start.py", line 1, in <module>
    from owlready import *
  File "C:\winpython\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\owlready\__init__.py", line 85
    def __init__(self, *Entities, ontology = None):
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Owlready is for Python 3 while you're using Python 2. Change your python version for it to work.

The invalid syntax error is because of the new Python 3 argument lists, see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists